# Adding google cloud armor to Terraform gke and kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-armor

I am trying to add google cloud armor to my Terraform project that deploys app using Kubernetes. I follow this example. But, in my case, I want to create this rules instead:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/examples/cloud-armor/main.tf

**Close all traffics for all IPs on all ports but open traffic for all IPs on port 80 and 443**

- Then I added a file also called `web_application_firewall.tf` under the directory `terraform/kubernetes` with the following configuration:

```
# Cloud Armor Security policies
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "web-app-firewall" {
  name        = "armor-security-policy"
  description = "Web application security policy to close all traffics for all IPs on all ports but open traffic for all IPs on port 80 and 443"

  # Reject all traffics for all IPs on all ports
  rule {
    description = "Default rule, higher priority overrides it"

    action   = "deny(403)"
    priority = "2147483647"

    match {
      versioned_expr = "SRC_IPS_V1"

      config {
        src_ip_ranges = ["*"]
      }
    }

    
  }

  # Open traffic for all IPs on port 80 and 443
  #rule {
  #  description = "allow traffic for all IPs on port 80 and 443"

  #  action   = "allow"
  #  priority = "1000"

  #  match {
  #    versioned_expr = "SRC_IPS_V1"

  #    config {
  #      src_ip_ranges = ["*"]
  #    }
  #  }
  #}
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall-allow-ports" {
  name    = "firewall-allow-ports"
  network = google_compute_network.default.name

  allow {
    protocol = "icmp"
  }

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80"]
  }

  source_tags = ["web"]
}

resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "test-network"
}
```

Here, I deactivate port 445 but after I redeployed, I still have an access to the web app. Could you please let me know what I did wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I literally came here to post a similar question.

Comment: @shuti Did you wait a couple of minutes before test? Which terraform did you use? In your terraform manifes you also have `allow traffic` part commented?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to clarify a few things.

**Cloud Armor**

> [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/cloud-armor-overview) provides protection only to applications running behind an external load balancer, and several features are only available for external HTTP(S) load balancer.

In short, it can filter IP addresses but cannot block ports, it's firewall role.

In question you have `deny` rule for all IP's and `allow` rule (which is commented), however both rules have `src_ip_ranges = ["*"]` which applies to all IPs which is a bit pointless.

**Terraform snippet**.

I have tried to apply [terraform-provider-google](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/examples/cloud-armor/main.tf) with your changes, however I am not sure if this is exactly what you have. If you could post your whole code it would be more helpful to replicate this whole scenario as you have.

As I mentioned previously, to block ports you need to use Firewall Rule. Firewall Rule applies to a specific VPC network, not all. When I tried to replicate your issue I found that you:

***Create new VPC network***

```
resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "test-network"
}
```

***Created Firewall rule***

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall-allow-ports" {
  name    = "firewall-allow-ports"
  network = google_compute_network.default.name

  allow {
    protocol = "icmp"
  }

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80"]
  }

  source_tags = ["web"]
}
```

**But where did you create VMs? If you followed github code, your VM has been created in `default` VPC:**

```
  network_interface {
    network = "default" ### this line
    access_config {
      # Ephemeral IP
    }
```

In [Terraform doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#network_interface) you can find information that this value indicates to which network the VM will be attached.

> `network_interface` - (Required) Networks to attach to the instance. This can be specified multiple times.

**Issue Summary**

So in short, you have created new VPC (`test-network`), Created VPC rule (`"firewall-allow-ports"`) to allow only `ICMP` protocol and `TCP` protocol on port `80` with `source_tags = web` for new VPC - `test-network` but your VM has been created in `default` VPC which might have different firewall rules to allow whole traffic, allow traffic on port 445 or many more variations.

[image]
[image]

**Possible solution**

Using `default` as the name of resource in terraform might be dangerous/tricky as it can create resources in different locations than you want. I have changed this code a bit to create a VPC network - `test-network`, use it for firewall rules and in resource `"google_compute_instance"`.

```
resource "google_compute_network" "test-network" {
  name = "test-network"
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall-allow-ports" {
  name    = "firewall-allow-ports"
  network = google_compute_network.test-network.name

  allow {
    protocol = "icmp"
  }

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80", "443"] ### before was only 80
  }

  source_tags = ["web"]
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "cluster1" {
  name         = "armor-gce-333" ### previous VM name was "armor-gce-222"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "test-network"
    access_config {

...
```

As you can see on the screens below, it created Firewall rule also for port 443 and in VPC `test-network` you can see VM `"armor-gce-333"`.

**Summary**
Your main issue was related that you have configured new VPC with firewall rules, but your instance was probably created in another VPC network which allowed traffic on port 445.

[image]
[image]